# From main method to subroutine

Tags: java, subroutine

I wrote my code and it works completely, but I didn't write my own methods. The point of the assignment is to practice using subroutines and that's what I have to use. I read about making my own methods--A LOT. But I still can't wrap my mind around it.

Here's a piece of my code. Can you help me by explaining how I'd make my own method with it and call it?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Display welcome message 
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Math Functions event!");
    Scanner keyIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner userInput;
    System.out.print("Press the ENTER key to toss the dice.");
    keyIn.nextLine();

    //roll dice
    Random rand = new Random();
    int tries = 0;

    int sum = 0;
    while (sum != 7 && sum != 11) {
    // roll the dice once
    int roll1 = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
    int roll2 = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
    sum = roll1 + roll2;
    System.out.println(roll1 + " + " + roll2 + " = " + sum);
    tries++;
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of a method giving you a random dice roll:

```
public static int rollDice()
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    int roll = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
    return roll;
}
```

You would call the function like this:

```
int roll = rollDice();
```

So it could be integrated in your program like this for example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Display welcome message 
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Math Functions event!");
    Scanner keyIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner userInput;
    System.out.print("Press the ENTER key to toss the dice.");
    keyIn.nextLine();


    int tries = 0;

    int sum = 0;
    while (sum != 7 && sum != 11) {
    // Here is where you call your newly created method
    int roll1 = rollDice();
    int roll2 = rollDice();
    sum = roll1 + roll2;
    System.out.println(roll1 + " + " + roll2 + " = " + sum);
    tries++;
    }
}
```

The idea is that you want to split up a complicated task into many smaller ones. This way it makes it much easier to debug. The above is just an example, but if you are performing an operation that you realise is repetitive, a function can never hurt.

Try to think about your function in the following way:

**1. What does my function do?**

**2. What data should it provide me with?**

**3. What is the minimum my function requires to provide me with this data?**

As for a function that counts the characters for a string as mentioned in the comments:

1. Your function counts the characters in a string.
2. The data that it provides you with is simply a number.
3. All you need to get this number is a string.

Given this information, we can come up with the following function protocol:

```
public static int countCharacters(String myString)
{
    int count = myString.length();
    return count;
}
```

The return type and value is an `int` as this is what it needs to provide you with, and `myString` is the only data the function needs to work. Thinking this way makes code much more maintainable, and you will be able to break up a complicated task into several very simple steps.

Comment: I tried the random dice roll you wrote as well as another one (a void method) and NetBeans wrote an error--cannot find symbol, symbol: variable rand, location: class JavaOlympics. Why is it doing this?

Comment: @Salma this most likely means that you have not declared rand. Before you use it, do: Random rand = new Random();

Comment: @Salma if you are still having a problem, send me ALL the code you have. It'll be easier to know exactly whats wrong.

Comment: It worked perfectly well! ... but now I'm having difficulty with other stuff. I need to make a method to count the characters in a String. It works in the main method perfectly well, but I need to use it as a method.

Comment: You broke it down so well. Makes perfect sense! Thank you!

Comment: @Salma No problem. Goodluck!